# How do I find Point3 Position by we know Point1 and Point2 Position and length of Line Point1 to Point2 and length of line Point1 to Point3?

Tags: python-3.x, math, geometry, line, point

I need a formula to calculate the position of the third point, by we knowing that the position of the Point1 and Point2 and the length of the line (Point1, Point2) and the length of the line (Point1, Point3).

[image: >>>> this is a picture of this question <<<<]

```
# We represent it as follows:

Point1 as P1, Point2 as P2, Point3 as P3
P1 = (2, 16) or P1x,P1y = (2, 16)
P2 = (8, 10) or P2x,P2y = (8, 10)

length of the line (P1, P2) as L1, Length of the line (P1, P3) as L2
# I want to make length of the L2 longer than L1 ( so I plus 5 to length of the line L1 )
L1 = 8.5
L2 = L1 + 5 = 13.5 

Find : Point 3 => P3 = (P3x = ?, P3y =?)
```

This is my code: how I find the length of the line.

```
import math
def calculateDistance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    dist = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
    return dist
```

So How we can find position of P3?

```
Find : P3 = (P3x = ?, P3y =?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vectors P1->P3 and P1->P2 are collinear, which means the coordinates of P1->P3 are proportional to the coordinates of P1->P2; and the proportionality factor must be exactly the ratio of lengths `length(P1->P3) / length(P1->P2)`.

This gives you an equation for P3x and P3y:

```
P3x - P1x == (L2 / L1) * (P2x - P1x)
P3y - P1y == (L2 / L1) * (P2y - P1y)
```

Turning this into a definition for P3x and P3y:

```py
ratio = L2 / L2
P3x = P1x + ratio * (P2x - P1x)
P3y = P1y + ratio * (P2y - P1y)
```

Note that you don't need to define your own `distance` function; there is already one in the standard library `math` module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.dist

```py
from math import dist

print( dist((2,16), (8,10)) )
# 8.485281374238571
```

Comment: I do not know how to thank you to fit, when I solve this equation, I was so excited to tears.
You know, when we spend almost a week trying to solve a problem, but we still can not solve it, and when we ask for help, but no one can help us.
And then suddenly someone came to spend his time and valuable thoughts to help us, we really thank the senior, I wish you good health, success in all tasks.